# featherjs callback is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, feathersjs

I'm trying to use feathersjs, but I can't get past the sample programs (the todo list on the feathers.js main site). The only thing that gets passed into the functions is the received data. `param` and `callback` are always undefined.

```
var myService = {
  find: function(params, callback) {},
  get: function(id, params, callback) {},
  create: function(data, params, callback) {},
  update: function(id, data, params, callback) {},
  patch: function(id, data, params, callback) {},
  remove: function(id, params, callback) {},
  setup: function(app, path) {}
}
```

What am I doingn wrong? do I need to use an older version? I'm currently using "latest" for feathers in my `package.json`

Edit:

I quite literally copy-pasted the example code from http://feathersjs.com/#documentation

Edit: Source files added:

```
// app.js
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var compression = require("compression");
var express = require("express");
var feathers = require("feathers");
var http = require("http");
var io = require("socket.io");

var v1 = require("./lib/v1");
var config = require("./lib/config");

var app = feathers()
    .configure(feathers.socketio())
    .use(bodyParser.json())
    .use("/v1", v1)

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
```

and

```
//lib/v1.js
var v1Service = {
    find: function(params, callback) {
        console.log("finding");
        callback(null, [{
            "uuid": "blahblahblah"
        }]);
    },
    get: function(id, params, callback) {
        console.log("geting");
        callback(null, {
            "uuid": "blahblahblah"
        });
    },
    create: function(data, params, callback) {
        console.log("creating, args:" + JSON.stringify(callback));
        callback(null, {
            "uuid": "blahblahblah"
        });
    },
    update: function(id, data, params, callback) {
        console.log("updating");
        callback(null, {
            "uuid": "blahblahblah"
        });
    },
    patch: function(id, data, params, callback) {
        console.log("patching");
        callback(null, {
            "uuid": "blahblahblah"
        });
    },
    remove: function(id, params, callback) {
        console.log("removeing");
        callback(null, {
            "uuid": "blahblahblah"
        });
    },
    setup: function(app, path) {
        console.log("setup");
    }
}

module.exports = v1Service;
```

Edit: added error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.v1Service.get [as _super] (/api_dev/lib/v1.js:11:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/api/node_modules/feathers/lib/mixins/promise.js:6:30)
    at Object.self.(anonymous function) [as get] (/api/node_modules/feathers/node_modules/uberproto/lib/proto.js:61:21)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/api/node_modules/feathers/lib/providers/socket/commons.js:27:23)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.onevent (/api/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:327:8)
    at Socket.onpacket (/api/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:287:12)
    at Client.ondecoded (/api/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:185:14)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (/api/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
    at Decoder.add (/api/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:247:12)
```

Comment: How is your app setup & routes ? Probably the error is there

Comment: okay, added the relevant source files

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my client-side javascript. I was using "emit" incorrectly:

```
var sock = io.connect();
sock.emit("v1::create", {"some":"data"})
```

The above javascript is incorrect. Two additional parameters need to be supplied:

```
var sock = io.connect();
sock.emit("v1::create", {"some":"data"}, {}, function(){ console.debug("IN CALLBACK") })
```

I didn't think the problem would be from the client-side code, but it is

Comment: The next version (1.1) will make sure that this won't be an issue anymore.